# Create an alias for the word "git"

Tags: git, command-line

I see that you can add aliases in your git configs to do something like this `aa = add --all`... but you still need to type `git` before the `aa` is there a way to create an alias for the word "git"? So something like `gaa` would be `git add --all`?

Comment: That would be something you'd do in your shell, and I guess would vary slightly depending on whether you use bash, zsh, a windows shell, etc.

Comment: Ahh I see.. that would make sense. For further information I am using zsh. I will do some research with that info.

Answer (score 1):

For `zsh`, add the following to your `~/.zshrc` file (or `~/.bashrc` for `bash`):

```
alias gaa='git add --all'
```